# `\xymatrix` line without arrowhead and curved

Tags: xymatrix

I would like to plot an arrow without head AND curved. I can achieve both goals separately but not on the same arrow:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \xymatrix{
    &G\ar@{-}[d]^{\le}\ar@{-}[ddl]_{\le}\ar@/^/[ddr]^{\triangleleft}&\\
    &HN\ar@{-}[dl]_{\le}\ar@{-}[dr]^{\triangleleft}&\\
    H\ar@{-}[dr]_{\triangleleft}&&N\ar@{-}[dl]^{\le}\\
    &H\cap N&
    }
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would like to merge

```
\ar@{-}[ddr]^{\triangleleft}
```

and

```
\ar@/^/[ddr]^{\triangleleft}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an extra `@`.  (And by the way, please don't use `minimal`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \xymatrix{
        &G\ar@{-}[d]^{\le}\ar@{-}[ddl]_{\le}\ar@{-}@/^/[ddr]^{\triangleleft}&\\
    &HN\ar@{-}[dl]_{\le}\ar@{-}[dr]^{\triangleleft}&\\
    H\ar@{-}[dr]_{\triangleleft}&&N\ar@{-}[dl]^{\le}\\
    &H\cap N&
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

For reference see the answer to exercise 9 in section 2.3 of [xyguide](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf)

Comment: I tried different combinations...but not this easy one, thank you.